# How to serialize a SecTrustRef object?

Tags: macos, trust, security-framework

I have a `SecTrustRef` object from the system that I'd like to evaluate myself. Just calling `SecTrustEvaluateAsync` will be sufficient for this job. The problem is, I must evaluate it in a different process as only this other process has access to the keychains where the CA certificates are stored that may cause evaluation to succeed.

The two processes have an IPC link that allows me to exchange arbitrary byte data between them but I don't see any way to easily serialize a `SecTrustRef` into byte data and deserialize that data back to an object at the other process. There doesn't seem to be a persistent storage mechanism for `SecTrustRef`.

So am I overlooking something important here, or do I really have to get all the certs (`SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex`) and all the policies (`SecTrustCopyPolicies`) and serialize these myself?

And if so, how would I serialize a policy?

For the certificate (`SecCertificateRef`) it's rather easy, I just call `SecCertificateCopyData` and later on `SecCertificateCreateWithData`.

But for policies I can only call `SecPolicyCopyProperties` on one side and later on `SecPolicyCreateWithProperties`, however the later one requires a 2nd parameter, a `policyIdentifier` and I see no way to get that value from an existing policy. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through the [source of the Security framework](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/), I finally figured it out how to copy a `SecPolicyRef`:

- `SecPolicyCreateWithProperties` wants what it calls a "policyIdentifier". It's a constant like `kSecPolicyAppleIPsec`.
- This does not get stored directly by the function, it's comparing the value and calling dedicated internal "initializers" (like `SecPolicyCreateIPsec`).
- These in turn call `SecPolicyCreate` (which is private). They end up passing the same identifier value that you passed to `SecPolicyCreateWithProperties`.
- And this value then gets stored as-is in the `_oid` field!

The identifier is actually the OID. You can get it either via `SecPolicyCopyProperties(policy)` (stored in the dictionary with key `kSecPolicyOid`) or via `SecPolicyGetOID` (but that returns it as an inconvenient `CSSM_OID`). Some of those specialized initializers also use values from the properties dictionary passed to `SecPolicyCreateWithProperties`, those should be present in the copied properties dictionary already.

---

So this gives us:

Serialization:

```
CFDictionaryRef createSerializedPolicy(SecPolicyRef policy) {
    // Already contains all the information needed.
    return SecPolicyCopyProperties(policy);
}
```

Deserialization:

```
SecPolicyRef createDeserializedPolicy (CFDictionaryRef serialized) {
    CFStringRef oid = CFDictionaryGetValue(serialized, kSecPolicyOid);
    if (oid == NULL || CFGetTypeID(oid) != CFStringGetTypeID()) {
        return NULL;
    }

   return SecPolicyCreateWithProperties(oid, serialized);
}
```

---

To reproduce the original SecTrustRef as closely as possible, the anchors need to be copied as well. There is an internal variable `_anchorsOnly` which is set to `true` once you set anchors. Unfortunately, there is no way to query this value and I've seen it being `false` in trusts passed by `NSURLSession`, for example. No idea yet on how to get this value in a public way.

Another problematic bit are the exceptions: if `_exceptions` is NULL but you query them via `SecTrustCopyExceptions(trust)`, you do get data! And if you assign that to the deserialized trust via `SecTrustSetExceptions(trust, exceptions)` you suddenly end up with exceptions that were not there before and can change the evaluation result! (I've seen those suddenly appearing exceptions lead to an evaluation result of "proceed" instead of "recoverable trust failure").